# Visual StudioでOSSをビルドする方法

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio

こんにちは
私はいままでautotoolsを使用してC++のビルドを管理していました。

これをVisualStudioでもビルド出来るようにしようと考えて、bakefileというツールでvc++向けのプロジェクトファイルを作りました。

ですが、リポジトリには依存しているライブラリの多くは入っていません。（※libcurlやwxWidgetsなど）VisualStudioで開発する場合このようなOSSはどのように管理するのが正しいでしょうか？作成したソリューションの配下にこれらを置く必要があるのでしょうか？

※一応自分でも調査はしており、nugetというパッケージマネージャーがあることを知っています。そのへんのVisualStudioの作法等知っておられる方がいれば教えてください
※できるだけ、リポジトリからソースコードをチェックアウトすると依存のライブラリは揃う状態に出来たらと思っています

Comment: 単なる目撃情報ですが `Gradle` で `VisualStudioSolution` や `VisualStudioProject` といった単語を見かけたことがあります。

Comment: C++のためにJavaを入れるのは…とは言えちょっと興味深いですね

Answer (score 3, accepted):

この辺のページが参考になるのではないでしょうか？

#### [.NETで開発モジュール導入が楽々に！ NuGet入門](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/chushin/nuget_01/nuget_01_01.html)

ページ下の方の「NuGetのインストール」の辺りに**Visual Studio 2010の［拡張機能マネージャー**］からインストールする方法が記載してあります。

Comment: 個人的にはこの辺りも参考になりました
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12890674/2565527

nugetを使えば依存ライブラリをpackages.configで指定できます。また、インポートしたnugetのライブラリはパス設定が自動でなされるためCXXFLAGSやLIBSのようなUNIX的な変数を設定しなくて良いことがわかりました。

ただし、依存ライブラリをインストールするにはGUIでの操作を行うか、パッケージマネージャーコンソールからの操作が必要みたいです。プロジェクトファイルを作成した段階での前準備としてそのようなインポート初理が出来ないのが残念です。